# Import Error when use templatetags in Django

Tags: python, django, templatetags

Well, when I'm trying to use 'inclusion' in Django, I met some confused problems that I can't solve it by myself.

There is the structures for my project.

```
MyProject---
            App1---
                   __init__.py
                   models.py
                   test.py
                   urls.py
                   views.py
            App2---
                   ...
            template---
                       App1---
                              some htmls
                       App2---
                              ...
            templatetags---
                           __init__.py
                           inclusion_cld_tags.py
            manage.py
            urls.py
            __init__.py
            settings.py
```

I have registered templatetags folder in the settings.py (Both in Installed APPS & TEMPLATE_DIRS).
But when I want to use {% load inclusion_test %} in my html, it raise an exception like this:

```
'inclusion_cld_tags' is not a valid tag library: Could not load template library from django.templatetags.inclusion_cld_tags, No module named inclusion_cld_tags
```

I think there is nothing wrong with my import work, how can I do with that?

Thanks for help!

My django version: 1.0+
My Python version: 2.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The templatetags folder [should live in the app folder](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout):

   ```
           App1---
                  __init__.py
                  models.py
                  test.py
                  urls.py
                  views.py
                  templatetags---
                          __init__.py
                          inclusion_test.py
                             ...
   ```
2. Did you registered the tag?

Example:

```
register = template.Library()   
@register.inclusion_tag('platform/templatetags/pagination_links.html')
def pagination_links(page, per_page, link):
```

Comment: Thanks for answering
1.I've tried to put the templatetags folder into one of my apps, but it also doesn't work. 
2.I've already registered it like the given example above & do 'from django import template' before asking this question.

Comment: Oh...Um...All right I've solved it finally.  =.=   You're right the templatetags folder should live in the app folder, after that I should change INSTALLED_APPS's settings in settings.py so that it can be properly placed in my project. After all, thanks for your help.